# Magic Crossword...

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

In the pattern shown, A,B , C, and D are prime numbers and all eight numbers are different. The sum along any 3-number row or column is the value of S. What is the smallest possible value of S?

[image]

Hi All,
So here is my problem, I did some thinking and this is what I got:

17+A+B=S

7+C+D=S

So on, and so on. I tried to replace numbers, but I was left with one equation, 3 variables. Is it possible to receive some help for this?

Comment: It may be more helpful to compare a row sum and a column sum which share an entry.  E.g. $17+A+B = S = 13+B+D$, so thus $D-A = 4$.  As I read your problem $S$ is not *required* to be prime, though it will of course be an odd number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A+C = B+D + 2\\
A-B+C-D = 2\\
A+B-C-D = -10\\
2A-2D = -8\\
D-A = 4\\
C-B = 6$

So now we go through the list of prime numbers looking for a gap of 6 and a gap of 4.

$(7,3)$ is the smallest pair with a gap of 4, but we can't use 7 (because it has already been used).  So, now we are looking at primes greater than 17.

The smallest pairs with a gap of 4 are $(23,19)$ and $(41,37)$
and the smallest pairs with a gap of 6 are $(29,23)$ and $(37,31)$

$(23,19),(37,31)$ minimize $S$

\begin{array}{}&&13\\17&19&31\\&37&23&7\\&11\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

Use the equations you have found to find $C-B$ and $D-A$
Establish that you cannot use $3$ or $5$
The first two should show you how to assign the smallest remaining primes.